# How can I add multiple white spaces between fields?

Tags: visualforce, css, ui

There are ways to create one white space `(&nbsp;, <br/>),` but I don't know how to create multiple consecutive white spaces between two fields. I've tried using InputHidden fields, `<br/> or &nbsp;` consecutively, blank outputlabels, but none of these has created more than one white space on the page.

Any ideas?

Example of what I'm trying to re-create in Visualforce:

[image]

Edit: The accepted answer works if the visualforce page is in edit mode, but in view mode, this happens:

[image]

I used `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem/>` between Field 2 and Field 3, but `<br/>` after Field 4. So using `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem/>` on view mode is problematic.

Comment: Some context around why would help. You could try simply adding padding or margin to one of the fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an apex:pageBlockSection, so you just need to add empty items, like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:outputField value="{!obj.field1}" />
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
    <apex:outputField value="{!obj.field2}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!obj.field3}" />
```

Comment: I was just about to write this and answer my own question! I should do more research before posting next time. Thanks!

Comment: @ESil This is a good question. I don't think there's anywhere that really just calls this out, so it's not something a typical developer would know until they need it.

Comment: I just edited my question to show a problem with using `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem />` like this - may I ask what you think?

Comment: @ESil View mode doesn't have the underlines normally (which is what you see between field 2-3, and can verify using standard page layouts using the "Blank Field" element), but using `<br />` outputs a cell that will be underlined. If you need consecutive items there, try `<apex:outputPanel/>`.